# Returning value from macro_rules! in Rust

Tags: rust

I am going through [Rust by Examples - Macros/DSL](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/macros/dsl.html)

The code shows:

```
macro_rules! calculate {
    (eval $e:expr) => {{
        {
            let val: usize = $e; // Force types to be integers
            println!("{} = {}", stringify!{$e}, val);
        }
    }};
}

fn main() {
    calculate! {
        eval 1 + 2 // hehehe `eval` is _not_ a Rust keyword!
    }

    calculate! {
        eval (1 + 2) * (3 / 4)
    }
}
```

Now I want my custom macro `calculate` to return the calculated value. I tried with the following:

```
macro_rules! calculate {
  (eval $e:expr) => {{
    let val: usize = $e;
    println!("{} = {}", stringify!{$e}, val);
    val
  }};
}
```

But it returns me error saying `error[E0308]: mismatched types in val, expected type (), found type i32`.

How can I modify the above macro to return the calculated value? Thanks.

Comment: The macro *is* returning the value, but you're using the macro in a context where a `()` is expected (because `main` returns `()`). Try assigning the result to a variable.

Comment: I think I know what's wrong with it. In the original src code, it should end each `calculate! {...}` macro call with a semi-colon!

Thanks for your input @FrancisGagné

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what's wrong with it. In the original src code, it should end each `calculate! {...}` macro call with a semi-colon.